# matlab z-transform

Tags: matlab, z-transform

I am trying to do the z-transform in matlab but I keep on getting an extremely large answer. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I can do matlab for simply problem but I don't understand the answer it gave me. Why is it so large? if anyone can plug it into matlab and help me it would be great.

**MatLab Code**

syms z
x=(2-((1/sqrt(2))+(sqrt(2)))*z^(-1)+z^(-2))/((1-sqrt(2)*z^(-1)+z^(-2))*(1-0.5*z^(-1)))

x=iztrans(x)

pretty(x)

x=vpa(x,7)

pretty(x)

**ANSWER IN MATLAB**
x =

0.8092564*0.5^n + (-1.0)^n*(- 0.7071068 - 0.7071068i)^(n - 1.0)*0.4604957i - (-1.0)^n*(- 0.7071068 + 0.7071068i)^(n - 1.0)*0.4604957i + 1.841983*(-1.0)^n*cos(2.356194*n) 
             n         n                           n - 1.0                    n                           n - 1.0                    n
0.8092564 0.5  + (-1.0)  (- 0.7071068 - 0.7071068i)        0.4604957i - (-1.0)  (- 0.7071068 + 0.7071068i)        0.4604957i + (-1.0)  cos(2.356194 n) 1.841983

**Answer in class:** y(k) = [0.8093(0.5)^k + 1.3572((1)^k)(cos(0.7854k-0.50047))]u(k)

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax. Unfortunately this question lacks formatting making it very difficult to read

Comment: try on an example, for example $\frac{1-z^{-6}}{1-z^{-1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{5} z^{-n}$ and see how it works.. Then correct your mistakes

Comment: i been trying it it matlab. is it formatting that is wrong?

Comment: Try using “simplify”.